# How do I allow users to type superscripts in inputs?

Tags: html, css, input

Something like this: https://giphy.com/gifs/l0Exj1s5ieHCTg4Fi

Code for superscript

```
sup {      
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
} 
sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible using just an input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do it (knowing that it's impossible to do it with just an input) is to make a mini-markdown formatting (like the input of stackoverflow website when you're adding a comment)

Here is an example: (try and type this `57**7** + 20**-1**` inside the input and see what happens).

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var result = document.getElementById('result');
var desired = document.getElementById('desired');

input.oninput = function(){
  var v = this.value;
  var d = v.replace(/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/g, "^$1");
  v = v.replace(/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/g, "<sup>$1</sup>");
  result.innerHTML = v;
  desired.textContent = d;
}
```

```html
Input goes here: <input id='input'/><br>Result is seen here: <span id='result'></span><br>Desired format is seen here: <span id='desired'></span>
```

It's goes over the input's value replacing every text surrounded `**` with a `sup` tag and then show the result inside a span using `innerHTML`.

Comment: How do I change it such that typing "^" changes to superscript instead of **?

Comment: @kaien But how would you determine the end of the supscript then?

Comment: Do you mean surrounded in `^`?

Comment: Like how do I change 2** 2 ** to Math.pow(2, 2); and display the results @ibrahimmahrir

Comment: @kaien You want to get a string in this format: `22^7 + 8^2` so you can process it?

Comment: Yeah @ibrahimmahrir